# Access to a property called inside an ItemTemplate outside its binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, itemssource

Having this Properties and an ItemsControl binding to one of them:

```
Public Property Description As String
    Get
        Return _description
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _description = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Options As List(Of ItemOption)
    Get
        Return _options
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of ItemOption))
        _options = value
    End Set
End Property

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource OptionsTemplate}"/>
```

In the ItemTemplate I have access to the properties of the property called Options, of course. But it is possible to have access to the property called Description inside this ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **RelativeSource**.

For example this is how could be your **OptionTemplate**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OptionTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OptionTemplate"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;ssembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:prism1="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >

   <Grid>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" />
       <!-- Your others controls -->
   </Grid>

</UserControl>
```